# Using a MacBook's builtin sudden motion sensor with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

With the following code I can get the value of the "Sudden Motion Sensor", which is build into MacBooks:

```
Dynamic@ControllerState[{"X", "Y", "Z"}, ControllerPath -> {"Sudden Motion Sensor"}]
```

I want to use the values to control some variables in a `Manipulate` statement, however this doesn't seems to work:

```
Manipulate[x,"X" -> {x, -1, 1}, ControllerPath -> "Sudden Motion Sensor"]
```

Comment: off topic but do you know which apple laptops have SMS? a macbook I had did have an SMS, my current air does not seem to have one (or at least I cannot see any indication via pmset, mathematica does not find it etc). this despite not finding any info anywhere about it not being included in SSD notebooks.

Comment: @acl It would only make sense to have in MacBooks with a HDD for its original purpose, but i don't know.

Comment: @acl Here it is: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1935, only HDD MacBooks have it.

Comment: Thanks, I read "All Intel-based Mac notebooks have Sudden Motion Sensor technology" and somehow skipped over "Computers with Solid State Drives (SSD) or Flash Storage do not use SMS"...

Comment: For what is worth: I have a 2013 MBP retina with SSD and it does have a motion sensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can set variables equal to the controller values like below.  They can then be used in a computation.  Here I just scaled them by `a`.

```
Manipulate[
 {x0, y0, z0} = ControllerState[{"X", "Y", "Z"}, ControllerPath -> {"Sudden Motion Sensor"}];
 a {x0, y0, z0},
 {a, 1, 100}
 ]
```

Controlling the view point of 3D graphics could be fun, except that it's rather shaky on my computer.  Here the `ViewVector` is determined by the controller values, and `a` changes the plot:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[x^2 + a y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ViewVector -> Dynamic[{-5 Normalize@ControllerState[{"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
        ControllerPath -> {"Sudden Motion Sensor"}], {0, 0, 0.5 + a/2}}],
  SphericalRegion -> True],
 {a, 0.5, 2}
 ]
```

But I find my SMS rather noisy and in need of smoothing.  Also my "Y" coordinate seems to take on only two values, plus or minus `0.0039`.

---

Or perhaps one would like to see a slider:

```
Manipulate[
 x,
 {x, -1, 1,
    Slider[Dynamic[x, x = ControllerState["X", ControllerPath -> {"Sudden Motion Sensor"}]], {-1, 1}] &}
 ]
```

However, the `Dynamic` inside `Slider` overrides the usual action of the `Slider`.  It basically just displays its position according to the sensor's x value.

Comment: That doesn't directly modify `a`. Isn't it possible to do that?

Comment: @Tyllo Do you want `a` set equal to one of the SMS coordinates, or some function of them?

Comment: Nevermind, it works perfectly.